# How are references to .net standard/.net "full" assemblies resolved?

Tags: .net, .net-standard

I'd like to understand how .net standard and .net full can coexist in a single solution, and would there be some problems in this side-by-side development.

So here's a (not-so-imaginary) setup:

- `Serilog`, shipped as nuget package containing both .net Standard 1.0 and .net 4.5 assemblies
- project `LibStd` targeting .net Standard 1.0

  - references `Serilog` (.net Standard 1.0 assembly)
- project `LibFull` targeting .net 4.5.2

  - references `Serilog` (.net 4.5 assembly)
- project `Startup` targeting .net 4.5.2

  - references `LibStd` and `LibFull`

When I build this solution, target `bin` may contain either Standard or 4.5 Serilog's assembly (depending on the build order). *Either* way, everything seems to work (the code produces intended results, logging works, so far so good). If I try dumping the referenced types (Serilog's `ILogger`, for example), I see that they come from whichever assembly lies in `bin` (i.e., `LibStd` may call upon type from Serilog 4.5 w/o any issue). So far, so good.

My question is: is this supposed to work this way? Can I rely on this working in future? Or should I be on lookout for some unexpected behavior and avoid mixing Standard and Full versions of the same dependency in one application?